# Wrong pixel data of bitmap file

Tags: c

I am trying to code a program that works to downscale a bitmap file. I can read successfully the size of the file and height and width values but I have to get RGB values of pixels and assign them into pixels array. But I get irrelevant values and I couldn't understand why I'm not getting the exact values of pixels. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bitmap.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *bmp_input;

    bmp_input=fopen("itu.bmp","rb");

    BITMAPFILEHEADER fh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER fi;

    fread(&fh, sizeof(fh),1,bmp_input);
    fread(&fi, sizeof(fi),1,bmp_input);

    int *pixels;
    pixels= malloc(sizeof(fh.bfSize-54));

    fread(pixels, sizeof(pixels),1,bmp_input);

    fclose(bmp_input);


    printf("bfSize: %d\n", fh.bfSize);
    printf("Width: %d\n", fi.biWidth);
    printf("Height: %d\n",fi.biHeight);
    printf("First pixel data: %d %d %d",*pixels,*pixels+1,*pixels+2);
    return 0;
}
```

And the values that i get are here in the picture:

[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaURm.png)

Header File:bitmap.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t bfType;
    uint32_t bfSize;
    uint16_t bfReserved1;
    uint16_t bfReserved2;
    uint32_t bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t biSize;
    int32_t  biWidth;
    int32_t  biHeight;
    uint16_t biPlanes;
    uint16_t biBitCount;
    uint32_t biCompression;
    uint32_t biSizeImage;
    int32_t  biXPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t  biYPelsPerMeter;
    uint32_t biClrUsed;
    uint32_t biClrImportant;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that for a [mre] the content of "bitmap.h" is needed.

Comment: `pixels= malloc(sizeof(fh.bfSize-54));` You try to access `bfSize` before reading the header.

Comment: `fread(pixels, sizeof(pixels),1,bmp_input);` You know that `sizeof(pixels);` is 4, maybe 8, i.e. the size of a pointer variable; aren't you?

Comment: You are assuming the pixels start immediately after the 2 headers instead of using `bfOffBits`

Comment: The size of the image data is given in the header and it isn't necessarily its width * height * depth. It can be more because of the row stride.

Comment: You might be reading 4 components at a time, not sure, but you should be working in bytes... *pixels should max at 255 if you’d have a byte/unit8 char type.

Comment: I changed the sizeof(pixels) to sizeof(int) and the order of pixels array definition but I still get that values

Comment: Please don't correct the code on-the-fly to make it a "moving target" - this site isn't a "live" debugging session.

Comment: `sizeof(fh.fbSize-54)` will be 4 or 8. It's equivalent to `sizeof(unsigned int)` assuming that fbSize is defined as an unsigned int.

Comment: No usage of `sizeof` is going to get you the size of the image. Not in `sizeof(fh.bfSize-54)` nor in `sizeof(int)` nor in `sizeof(pixels)`. The only time that `sizeof` will work is when the pixel data is already defined as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the data into a byte buffer rather than an int buffer. The colors in a BMP file are stored using 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24 or 32 bits per pixel, so you need to extract the red, green and blue components more carefully than you're doing. It looks like your particular bmp uses 24 bits per pixel (because size is roughly three times the width and height). Thus you can read the components as single bytes, with each pixel three bytes long. For bytes, I use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` although `unsigned char` could be used instead.

The components in 24bpp are stored in the order blue, green, red.

Here's some example code that prints out the colours of every pixel in the image, assuming it's 24 bpp.
It would be better to check the `bpp` field of bitmap header to handle the pixel access correctly. Sorry, I don't know what the exact name of the field is in your header, because you don't provide it. More error checking would also be desirable. The code is untested, because I don't have access to your header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "bitmap.h"
 
int main(){
    FILE *bmp_input;

    bmp_input=fopen("itu.bmp","rb");

    BITMAPFILEHEADER fh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER fi;

    fread(&fh, sizeof(fh),1,bmp_input);
    fread(&fi, sizeof(fi),1,bmp_input);

    size_t pix_size = fh.bfSize-54;
    uint8_t *pixels = malloc(pix_size);
    if (!pixels) return 2;
    fclose(bmp_input);

    if (fread(pixels, 1, pix_size, bmp_input) != pix_size) return 1;
    int row_width = (3 * fe.biWidth + 3) & ~3; // round up to multiple of 4
    for (int j = 0; j < fi.biHeight; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fi.biWidth; i++) {
            int index = row_width * j + 3 * i;
            printf("pix[%d,%d]=RGB(%02X, %02X, %02X)\n", i, j, pixels[index+2], pixels[index+1], pixels[index]);
        }
    }
    free(pixels);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that from a software-engineering point of view, reading binary file formats by reading in data directly into a struct invites security and portability problems (for example, you probably implicitly depend on integers being 32 bits, and little-endian, and structs being packed a certain way). But I guess that this is just a learning exercise.

Comment: I think you've overlooked that there might be a colour table, and the 'stride' of the image. The array 'width' isn't always `biWidth` but a multiple of 4.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, and it won't work if there's compression either :)

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that there is no table for a 24/32-bit image, but not that the row length will be right.

Comment: You're right, I've rounded up the row length to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: I again tried your implementation of using unit and size_t, but I still can't get the rgb values. Its just incrementing 1 by 1 not gives the rgb values